# Cooldown on key presses Javascript

Tags: javascript, keycode

I have coded this game inspired by The Coding Train's Snake Game and I can't figure a problem out. If the player presses both the right button and the down button, for example, they would just turn to the opposite direction, which would just kill them. I wonder how I would set a cooldown on the keys opposite of eachother. I'm using the p5js library.

I appreciate any help!

```
  this.dir = function(x, y) {
    this.xspeed = x;
    this.yspeed = y;
  }   

    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW && s.yspeed != 1) {
       s.dir(0, -1);
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW && s.yspeed != -1) {
       s.dir(0, 1);
  } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW && s.xspeed != -1) {
      s.dir(1, 0);
  } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW && s.xspeed != 1) {
       s.dir(-1, 0);
  }
```

Comment: What key event do you have this handler added to? Can you provide all of this handler function and the code adding the event listener(s)?